# How to create a regular grid with varying cell sizes for anonymising point data (ideally in Python/GeoPandas)

Tags: qgis, python, vector-grid, point-in-polygon

I have some point data that represents households and I would like to anonymise them so that you can't see which particular house a point relates to, but you can still know rougly where the house is.

One way to do this is to create a regular grid (fishnet) that covers the study area and then snap each point to its parent grid cell. The problem with this approach is that some cells have very few points in them so they may not be anonymous. E.g. if a cell only has one point in it, and there is only one real house in that cell, then we know which house the point belongs to.

To avoid this problem I would like to create a grid that has larger cells in areas where the points are sparse. For example, the grid could be created such that each cell is ideally 100*100m, but will be larger if a cell has fewer than *N* points in it (e.g. *N=5*).

Any suggestions for how I might be able to do this, ideally (but not necessarily) using Python tools?

Comment: What have you tried because unless you add a Python code attempt your question will be closed

Comment: A tessellated grid  of course presents itself, but you need to play with that to see when to promote to parent 200x200 cells (or start at 400x400, since 100x100 seems awful small for anonymizing), and when to merge neighbors 100x200/200x100.

Comment: Having given an answer I would still say that I would personally rather prefer to apply a (different for each point) randomized translation to every point. Depending on your datasets (number of samples and/or density) it would be better both for anonymization and to keep the data consistent. however this work best with a high count samples datasets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are open to using qgis I have a simple process that does what you want simply:

1. First step: create the number of enclosing grids you want with the "Create Grid" tool from the qgis toolbox, covering your points' extent
   [image]
   to have a similar result:
   [image]
2. Second step: Run the following python script to obtain the final result:

```py
points = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("points")[0]
small_grid = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("Grid1000x1000")[0]
big_grid = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("Grid2000x2000")[0]

idx_sg = QgsSpatialIndex(small_grid)
idx_bg = QgsSpatialIndex(big_grid)
idx_points = QgsSpatialIndex(points)

dict_change_geometries = {}

for point in points.getFeatures():
    small_grid_spot = small_grid.getFeature(idx_sg.intersects(point.geometry().boundingBox().buffered(0.0001))[0])
    nb_points_in_small_grid = len(idx_points.intersects(small_grid_spot.geometry().boundingBox().buffered(0.0001)))
    
    if nb_points_in_small_grid < 5:
        dict_change_geometries[point.id()] = small_grid_spot.geometry().centroid()
    else:
        big_grid_spot = big_grid.getFeature(idx_bg.intersects(point.geometry().boundingBox().buffered(0.0001))[0])
        dict_change_geometries[point.id()] = big_grid_spot.geometry().centroid()

points.dataProvider().changeGeometryValues(dict_change_geometries)
```

Final result:
[image]

You can add grid levels in the script easily or change the switching to parent condition (n<5) to something else

This can be done similarly outisde qgis with the corresponding tools (geopandas, rtree, ...) all you need are grids and indexes

Comment: Thanks @Louis this does exactly what I needed. I hadn't thought about tesselating different sized grids first. I'll try to put an example in pure python together using the same technique to post here, but for my immediate use QGIS is fine.

Comment: More often than not easier is better.
A "smarter" way to do this would be create a small enough grid that all grid rectangles would only contain either nothing or one point; then start merging until a certain size (grid size or number of points) is achieved. 
However it raises the same problems as the simple solution but adds another problem with outliers who will be moved even farther away from their original location